# How can I write different information to cells on varying number of sheets from a named range on a summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA, piecing my code together from previous sheets created by others and what I've found online, working backwards basically.

I have a master workbook I am trying to create. It starts with two worksheets. The first (Start) will house some macros affecting all new worksheets, the second (Template) is a template for generating the remaining worksheets. On Start are a set of two ranges (of varying but equal size), one used to generate the new worksheets from Template; both to write themselves into a specific cell on each of the new worksheets.

Thus far I have managed to:
- Write a sub that generates the new sheets from Template and write from Range 1 on Start into cell "C6" on each of the new sheets. The value of "C6" on Template (1) is equal to cell 1 of the Range 1 on Start, the value of "C6" on Template (2) is equal to cell 2 of the Range 1 on Start, and so on and so forth.
- Write a sub to loop through all new Template worksheets and write a value from Range 2 on Start to cell "E6" on all Template worksheets.
- Write a sub to rename the newly generated worksheets from the values in Range 1 on Start.

What I am struggling with, is how to get the sub that loops through all sheets, to only loop through the sheets named "Template (1)" to "Template (X)" and to write the value from cell 1 of Range 2 to Template (1), cell 2 of Range 2 to Template (2), so on and so forth.

I found code on SO meant to loop through all sheets but one based on sheet name, it does not want to work for this purpose. Additionally I am getting the same value on each of the new worksheets, instead of the Range 2 value that corresponds to it's Range 1 counterpart.

```
Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook
Dim recap As Worksheet 'sheet codename for Template
Dim start As Worksheet 'sheet codename for Start
Dim CCell As Range, CSI As Range 'Range 2 is CSI

Set CSI = Sheets("START AND FINISH HERE").Range("CSI") 
Set CSI = Range(CSI, CSI.End(xlDown))

For Each CCell In CSI
    If CCell <> "" Then 
        Set recap = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next 
        Set recap = start(CCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If recap Is Nothing Then
        Range("E6").Value = CCell.Value 
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
    Next CCell
```

Comment: What is `start`?

Comment: I have my starting sheet codenamed start. After that all sheets build off the Template sheet which is currently codenamed recap in VBA.